# Cannot print error message from bmp::open

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print out the error it throws when bmp::open failed

```
let image_result = bmp::open(argument);
        let image = match image_result {
            Ok(i) => i,
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error! {error:?}");
            },
        };
```

However, I've been getting the below error message

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in Rust, the `match` statement has to return the same type from its `match` arms. So your first `match` arm

```
Ok(i) => i
```

returns a type of `Image` where as second match arm

```
Err(error) => {
     println!("Error! {error:?}");
}
```

does not return anything hence the compiler infer the return type as `()`(unit) type.

There are multiple ways you could solve this, but it's really depends upon how you want to handle with the error case. If your intention is to handle only `Ok` case, you could destructure the `Result`.

```
if let Ok(i) = bmp::open(argument) {
   print("Do something with {i}")
}
```

Alternatively you can [`panic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html) if the file is failed to open.

```
let image_result = bmp::open(argument);
let image = match image_result {
    Ok(i) => i,
    Err(error) => {
        panic!("Error! {error:?}");
    }
};
```

OR [with `unwrap_or_else`](https://docs.rs/bmp/latest/bmp/fn.open.html),

```
let img = bmp::open("test/rgbw.bmp").unwrap_or_else(|e| {
   panic!("Failed to open: {}", e);
});
```